# Setting the UITableViewCell from a picker selection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

So far I have made a `UITableView` in a `HabitViewControlle` with a button to add a new cell. When the cell is tapped, a `detialViewController` is revealed. In this View their is a `textField`, that when tapped a `UIPicker` is launched. I want to set the title of a `tableViewCell` to the picker selection.. I have made a `string` called `cellName` and I can send it to the other `ViewController`. I also made it so that when the `picker` is changed, I set the string `cellName` to the title I want the cell to be when the picker selection is selected. So I almost have it ready, except actually setting the cell title to the string when the cellName is set, and the picker selection has changed. If this didn't make sense, send a comment to me, and I will try to help, because I hard time writing my question into words

## habitViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface HabitViewController : UITableViewController <DetailViewDelegate> {

    UITableViewCell *cell;
}

@end
```

## .m

```
#import "HabitViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface HabitViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;

}
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *cellName2;


@end

@implementation HabitViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    [self.editButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.33 green:.33 blue:.33 alpha:1]];

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    addButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.33 green:.33 blue:.33 alpha:1];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    //if ([cellName isEqualToString:@"Hello World"]) {
   // }

}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _objects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"New Habit";

    NSLog(@"%@",self.cellName2);

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}

 // Override to support rearranging the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
 {
 }

 // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
 return YES;
 }

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

        /* assigning self as delegate, telling the detail view that I implement
         * setCellName2:, so it (the detailVC) can call it whenever it wants to.
         */
        [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];
    }
}
#pragma mark - DetailViewDelegate

// note: this is just a property setter so this is not actually needed
- (void)setCellName2:(NSString *)cellName {
    cellName = cellName;

   NSLog(@"%@",cellName);

    cell.textLabel.text = cellName;
}




@end
```

## DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol DetailViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)setCellName2:(NSString *)cellName;
@end

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate> {
    NSArray *PickerData;    
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *habitField;

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<DetailViewDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *cellName;

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *PickerData;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;

- (IBAction)backToRoot:(id)sender;

@end
```

## .m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

#import "HabitViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController () {
    UITableViewCell *_cell;

}

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize PickerData;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Posture",@"Paludies Abbs",@"Custom", nil];
    self.PickerData = array;

    [self.delegate setCellName2:self.cellName];

    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [toolBar sizeToFit];

    [toolBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red_navigation_bar.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                               target:self
                                                                               action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                                target:self
                                                                                action:@selector(releasePicker)];


    UIPickerView *Picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    Picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    Picker.delegate = self;
    doneButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];

    [toolBar setItems:@[flexSpace, doneButton] animated:YES];
    self.habitField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

    [self.habitField setInputView:Picker];

}
- (void)releasePicker {
    [self.habitField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)backToRoot:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [PickerData count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [self.PickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    int select = row;
    if (select == 0) {
       self.cellName = @"Posture";

        [self.view reloadInputViews];

       NSLog(@"%@ Is Selected", self.cellName);
    }
}


@end
```

Comment: What do you mean by title --  do you want to set the cell's text label's text to the string you select in the picker? What you have in cellFroRowAtIndexPath: makes no sense. First you set the text label's text to [object description], then in the next line you set it to "New Habit".

Comment: The title of the cells text label

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way. You shouldn't try to set the text of a cell in your delegate method, you should be adding (or changing) an entry in your array, _objects, and then reloading data (or just a specific row) of the table view. I'm still a little unsure of what you're trying to accomplish. When you create the new entry, you're putting a date into the array. But in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, you're just setting the label to "New Habit" (which overwrites the line above where you set it to [object description].

Comment: ohh, I want to override new habit

Comment: Not sure what that means. I'd like to help you, but you're not giving me enough information. What do you want to appear in the new cell when it's first created? You add a date to the array, but you're not showing that in the cell. Do you want that date to show first, then have it replaced by what's selected in the picker view? Or, do you want "New Habit" to be there initially, and then replaced by the picker's selected string?

Comment: I want habut to be shown initially, then replaced by the picker selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with this

First in your habitViewController.h do the following :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface HabitViewController : UITableViewController <DetailViewDelegate> {

    UITableViewCell *cell;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *cellNameSender;

@end
```

Then in your .m replace the code that looks like this with the following :

```
- (void)setCellName2:(NSString *)cellName {
    cellName = cellName;

    NSLog(@"%@",cellName);

    self.cellNameSender = cellName;
}

@end
```

and the same with this

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    cell.textLabel.text = self.cellNameSender;
}
```

Now the tableViewCell should show the posture is posture is selected.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to use your delegate to set  your picker in the didSelectRow method.  Like this:

DetailViewController.m:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    int select = row;
    if (select == 0) {
       self.cellName = @"Posture";

       [self.delegate setCellName2:self.cellName];

       NSLog(@"%@ Is Selected", self.cellName);
    }
}
```

and back in your habitViewController:

```
- (void)setCellName2:(NSString *)cellName {
    cellName = cellName;

    NSLog(@"%@",cellName);

    selectedCell.textLabel.text = cellName;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

You also have a few problems with "cell".  Assuming you have many rows, this will get re-used over and over again and will always contain the last cell it displayed, which will seldom be what you expect.

I would rename it to selectedCell and set it when the cell is touched and your other view triggered.

```
 @interface HabitViewController : UITableViewController <DetailViewDelegate> {

    UITableViewCell *savedCell;
}
```

I would set it here:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        if ([sender isKindOfClass[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            savedCell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;
        }

        /* assigning self as delegate, telling the detail view that I implement
         * setCellName2:, so it (the detailVC) can call it whenever it wants to.
         */
        [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

I would just use a temp cell in this method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"New Habit";

    NSLog(@"%@",self.cellName2);

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: The thing is logged, but the title still isnt set

Comment: Two errors."Use of undeclared identifier 'send'" and Used type 'UITableViewCell' where arithmetic or pointer type is required

Comment: if ([sender isKindOfClass[UITableViewCell class]]) instead of if ([send isKindOfClass...  see edited version above.

Comment: savedCell = (UITableViewCell *)sender; instead of savedCell = (UITableViewCell)sender;